# ViewState overwrites changes on dynamically added UserControl (in Placeholder) on PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, viewstate, page-lifecycle

In my ASP.NET application - having ViewState enabled - I can reset inputs by simply setting them again. Here is a basic simple sample that works:

**_TEST.aspx**

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />        
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" DataSource='<%# new string[] { "A", "B", "C" } %>' />
<asp:Button ID="b" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="b_Click" Text="Test 1" />
```

**_TEST.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.DataBind();
  this.ddl.SelectedValue = "B";
}

protected void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Updated");
}
```

In this example `ddl` will be bound with "A", "B" and "C" on `Page_Load` and it will always select "B". So when you change the selection and submit, it will be reset. Imagine this is used to reset some controls on specific conditions.

---

In my case I need this kind of behavior on a dynamically loaded `UserControl` that is added to a `Placeholder`. Because a `Placeholder` does not persist the content I need to recreate the controls on every postback. The `ViewState` seems to be okay with it. Here is a sample:

**_TEST.aspx**

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph" runat="server" />
```

**_TEST.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _TESTUC uc = (_TESTUC)this.Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/_TESTUC.ascx");
  this.ph.Controls.Add(uc);
}
```

**_TESTUC.ascx**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" DataSource='<%# new string[] { "A", "B", "C" } %>' />
<asp:Button ID="b" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="b_Click" Text="Test 2" />
```

**_TESTUC.ascx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.DataBind();
  this.ddl.SelectedValue = "B";
}

protected void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Updated");
}
```

Again, on every postback I want to reset the selection of the `DropDownList` for test purposes, but interestingly it remembers my selection.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing this question I came to the solution but decided to post it for other peoples, anyways.

It seems ASP.NET will load the `ViewState` between `Page_Init` and `Page_Load` in controls that are defined in ASPX, while it loads the `ViewState` between `Page_Load` and `Page_LoadComplete` in controls that are loaded in code-behind.

Setting the values in `Page_LoadComplete` solves the issue:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Page.LoadComplete += new EventHandler(this.Page_LoadComplete);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.DataBind();
}

protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.ddl.SelectedValue = "B";
}

protected void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Updated");
}
```